# Ideal of an ideal being an ideal itself

Tags: commutative-algebra

Take a commutative ring with unity (a.k.a. ring) $R$ and let $I$ be an ideal in $R$. Are the following true??

a) If $J$ is an ideal in $I$ (observed as a ring) , $J$ is not ideal in $R$(if this is true, please give me example)

b) If $J$ is a maximal ideal in $I$, then $J$ is ideal in $R$

c) If $J$ is ideal in $I$, and $I$ is maximal ideal in $R$, then $J$ is ideal in $R$

Comment: What do you mean by ring? Some books insist rings contain "1", in which case no proper ideal will be a ring

Comment: Some insist on that and others don't.  Also, a subring can have an identity which is not an identity of the whole ring.  Consider the 2x2 matrices.  Those which are zero except for the top left element are a subring.  This does not include the identity of the whole ring but it does have an identity.  It is not an ideal though.

Comment: Another example worth considering is $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Consider $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and $I=(2)$, $J=(4)$, then $J$ is an ideal in $I$ and $J$ is an ideal in $\mathbb{Z}$, therefore a) is false

Comment: Observe if b) is true then a) is false.